# Where is the address OpCodes.Ret uses stored? Can it be changed?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

Is there any way to change the address OpCodes.Ret jumps to? Can a method in IL change the call stack used by C#?

As far as I know in C++ you could just access the values on the stack and change return addresses and so on. In IL everything I tried to access the stack beyond the current method fails with the exception "InvalidProgramException".

my example code:

```
    public static void Test2()
    {
        var ma = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test2");
        DynamicMethod meth = new DynamicMethod("", null, null, ma.Module, true);
        ILGenerator il = meth.GetILGenerator();



        il.EmitWriteLine("Start to run the IL method");

        var t = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));



        //take the top of the stack (from the caller method) and put it into the variable t
        //this seems to be not possible?
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, t);

        //print the value from the stack
        il.EmitWriteLine(t);

        //load the value back from the field onto the stack to allow everything to preceed normally
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, t);

        //return
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Action a = (Action)meth.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));

        a();
    }
```

Comment: Who says that `ret` jumps to an address? The opcode specification says nothing about "jumping to an address". Neither for that matter does the C++ specification. If you can do that in C++, that's implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: Yes it probably compiler depended. Maybe this kind of access is not possible in C#. I am not sure. But internally the CLI has to store where to go after the method is finished at the RET command. I am looking for a hack not something that should be used in a real environment.

Comment: The stack is a data structure owned by the CLR; the way it uses the stack is an implementation detail, and you cannot safely make any assumptions about how it uses that data structure. For example, suppose you change the return address and then a security stack walk happens, or an exception happens?  The CLR might need the data structure on the stack to be correct in order to do the walk correctly. Don't change it; it's not yours to change.

Comment: If your intention is to use this as a way to call another method without retaining the current frame on the call stack, then you might want to consider the tailcall opcode prefix instead. Its much safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `OpCodes.Ret` IL instruction doesn't really do any jumping. Instead, the IL code is compiled to native machine code by the CLR and *that* is executed. What machine code is generated for some IL code depends on your architecture (x86, ARM, …) and it's an implementation detail of the CLR.

It makes sense to assume that on x86, the `ret` IL instruction is compiled to the `ret` x86 instruction, but it may not be, for example because the whole method might be inlined.

To do this, you could try modifying the stack using pointers, since that's where the address x86 `ret` jumps to is stored, but doing this is very dangerous (you can easily modify the wrong memory) and extremely fragile (since it's relying on the layout of the stack, which can easily change).

As an example, look at the following code:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A();
    }

    static void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A before");
        B();
        Console.WriteLine("A after");
    }

    static void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B before");
        C();
        Console.WriteLine("B after");
    }

    static unsafe void C()
    {
        int local;

        int* localPointer = &local;

        localPointer[2] = localPointer[4];
    }
}
```

If I run this *on my computer, in Debug mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>*, it prints:

```
A before
B before
A after
A after
```

This shows that I've successfully modified the call stack from `Main` → `A` → `B` → `C` to `Main` → `A` → `A` → `C`.

But it stops working when run in Release mode, when run using <kbd>F5</kbd> or when I add a local variable to `B` or `C`, showing how fragile this is.

So, it can be done, but **you should never ever do this** (except for educational purposes).

Comment: To be honest, I don't think there is any educational benifit here either. If someone wants to known how the callstack/calling conventions work then managed code is very much the wrong medium to use.

Comment: great answer :) So IL doesn't allow the manipulation on this level but after it compiles down to machine code it behaves similar to C/C++. I think it is educational :) For proper programming it might be a bad example but from a security perspective it is very interesting.